# NSIS installer script with TFS Build Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild, nsis

is it possible to utilize my NSIS installer script to make an automated build (daily) for my program in TFS 2010? The program isnt C#, it's actually small talk, so the installer being designed in NSIS was prior to our group being required to migrate source control into TFS.

Essentially the installer just copy/pastes the directory and shortcuts onto destination PC, and runs a regedit for the new parameters. I noted in the TFS build tool (which I'm extremely unfamiliar with) that it constantly wants me to point at a .proj file.. Does this mean I've got to convert our NSIS scripts into some .NET equivalent (if so how?) or is there a plugin of some sort to allow these guys to play nice together?

Comment: How so you run the NSIS installer script now?

Comment: VBS file where user inputs build No. that just runs NSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project support MSBuild to build it, you can use TFS Team Build directly. If your project doesn’t support MSBuild to build it, you need to provide a compiler which can build your project, and this compiler support run the command line to invoke it, so we can add the **InvokeProcess** activity(execute the command line) to invoke that compiler to build your project in build process template.

Here are useful blogs for your reference:

- http://donovanbrown.com/post/I-need-to-build-a-project-that-is-not-supported-by-MSBuild
- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2011/03/31/TFS-Build-Invoke-Process-Activity.aspx

Comment: I dont even have a project (in the VS2010 sense) All I have is our directory of files, an NSIS .nsi file, and a vbs script that runs the nsi file against NSIS on our server. Is there a way I can get TFS Build to use the VBS script alone, or will I need to make a project that invokes the script?

Comment: You need to create a empty solution and invoke the script. And customize the build process template as I mentioned to build your project.